# Uncertainty Principle Paradox

Tags: quantum-mechanics, heisenberg-uncertainty-principle

Consider 2 elementary particles connected together by a microscopic spring and being compressed. Now let go the spring, and two particles are able to move away from each other. We can measure the position of particle 1 and momentum of particle 2 to get momentum of particle 1 and position of particle 2, as they are mathematically related.
Does anyone have a solution to resolve this “paradox” in order for it to be compatible with the quantum uncertainty principle?

Comment: What's the point of using a spring for two particles to interact? How did you perform the measurements?

Comment: I am not sure why this is being downvoted. Note that the OP is new: we could encourage the OP to add more details on why they think that there is a mathematical relationship of the kind that is being suggested, or at the very least what they think the mathematical relationship is. An answer can then clarify that such a relationship is incorrect.

Comment: As an aside: not really a duplicate, but very similar in gist: https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/56793/why-cant-we-use-entanglement-to-defy-heisenbergs-uncertainty-principle?rq=1 (after all, I think the OP is suggesting that the spring set-up will end up generating an entangled state of the kind asked about in the linked post)

Answer (score 0):

When thinking there exists a paradox, be sure that you are mixing two mathematical frames together, in this case the quantum mechanical with the classical mechanics one.

Springs are objects that exist in classical mechanics. The Heisenberg uncertainty resides only in quantum mechanics. There are no mechanical springs in quantum mechanics, that you can connect and take away. As far as particles go there are the [three standard model forces,](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/Forces/funfor.html) (gravity is not yet definitely quantized), described by specific potentials due to the nature of the particles, and can only be explored with interactions, i.e. scatterings and decays.